# Adding foreign key data through django rest framework serializer

Tags: python-3.x, django, rest, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am new to django, I have two models `User` and `Todo`. `User` can have multiple todos, while creating the todos I want to pass user_id with `request.data`, but while including user_id or user field along with `request.data` I am getting validation error for `Todo` fields.
Here is the `User` model and `Todo` model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
  email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
  password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
  username = None
  name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
  is_email_verified = models.BooleanField(null=True)
  mobile = models.CharField(max_length=13, validators=[RegexValidator(regex=r'^(\+\d{1,3})?,?\s?\d{8,13}', message="Enter a valid mobile number")], default='+911234567890')

  USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
  REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['mobile']
```

```
class Todo(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=100)
  description = models.TextField(max_length=500)
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=0)
  created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.title

  class Meta:
    indexes = [
      models.Index(fields=['created_at']),
      models.Index(fields=['updated_at'])
    ]
```

Here is the `Todoserializer`:

```
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer, CharField
from todos.models import Todo
from users.models import User

class TodoSerializer(ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Todo
    fields = '__all__'
    read_only_fields = ['id', 'created_at', 'updated_at']
```

Here is the view for creating todos:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def create(request):
  user = request.user
  todo = TodoSerializer(data={ **request.data, 'user': user.pk })
  todo.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
  todo.save()
  return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK, data={'todo': todo})
```

The serializer doesn't get validated any time
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view try :

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def create(request):
  request.data['user'] = request.user
  todo = TodoSerializer(data=request.data)
  todo.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
  todo.save()
  return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK, data={'todo': todo.data})
```

Comment: request.data is immutable, so I used request.data.copy() to copy it and used the mutable version for manipulation,  but again assigning user to the dict didn't work, it showed `"user": [ "Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received User." ]`.  so I assigned dict key `"user"` to `request.user.id`, but that says `Object of type TodoSerializer is not JSON serializable` @Uzzal H. Mohammad

Comment: I suggest you to look into CreateApiVIews to avoid this kind of struggle.

Comment: Thank you @Uzzal H. Mohammed, I just wanted to add few changes in your answer, I needed to use a mutable copy of request.data to add user key there and the variable `todo` cannot be json serializable directly, `todo.data` was required there. And then it will work.

Comment: I see I missed that. Updated the answer.